# What's the door code?

Tags: lateral-thinking, keys-and-locks

You're running late to your first day on the job and after arriving at the meeting location, you see the orientation group just leaving without you through a door with a keypad.

[image]

Panicked, you confirm the door re-locked, and then pound on the door with no answer. In a last ditch effort, you ask the only person around, a janitor, if he knows the combination.

"24 equals."

You ask him to repeat himself since he's mumbling slightly.

He shouts at you, enunciating slowly and clearly, "24 equals!". Then he walks away looking angry.

After saying your thanks, you try it but immediately realize the combination isn't long enough. To submit a combination, 4 of either the numbers, X, or + need to be entered followed by the equal sign.

What do you do?

> NOTE: Guesses are welcome, I can say if the combination works so you can put yourself in the story. There is no limit to the number of guesses.
>
> NOTE 2: Random guessing isn't necessary (or how could this be considered a puzzle?)

Hint:

> You notice the janitor doesn't seem like a guy who likes riddles or math.

Comment: = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = . 24 equals.

Comment: @Angelplayer `****` = 4 characters

Comment: @Raystafarian There's no 0. My first thought was "204=" ("twenty" followed by "four") which I didn't put up as an answer for the same reason.

Comment: I guessed 1440 - I deleted it too soon. There's no 0 thanks @hvd

Comment: $24 = 4! = 4*3*2$

Comment: You enter 4 X 3 X but there's no space for 2. 4X3X doesn't work.

Comment: The latter two tags, on this, don't seem to apply.  I'm not sure on the first til we know the answer.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I feel like my tags got changed automatically, I put code but it changed to cipher.

Comment: I'm starting to not like riddles or math much after this one

Comment: @Raystafarian I know. I was just messing around.

Comment: I like the original wording; "enunciating slowly and clearly" seems misleading.

Comment: @Solocutor I was debating on that. I think depending on the person, adding that can either help or hurt but it does remove the ambiguity that the words were slurred in any way.

Comment: How about we go Roman? XX for 20 (XX4=)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It then dawns on me:

> 21+4=, guessing that the janitor interpreted the plus sign as a t. (sound: two-one-tee-four)

---

Old answer:
I enter

> 2134=

because I believe

> he slurred the 213 together to sound like "twenty".

Comment: You try 2134 and it doesn't work. But you feel like you're getting very close.

Comment: The question states that the janitor enunciated clearly. I feel like it would be hard to slur numbers together given that wording.

Comment: @dpwilson You're right, the janitor said 24 equals very slowly and clearly.

Comment: You enter 21+4= and the door opens! You run ahead and sneak into the orientation group saving your job.

Comment: but that's twenty one t four equals

Comment: ....heh  Yeah, I had the T, but I'm still not completely convinced on the Two One amalgamation. =D

Comment: @question_asker When people say combinations, they generally say each number (one two three five not twelve thirtyfive). "Two one tee four"

Comment: "21+4=" is 5 characters and the graphic shows 4 spaces.

Comment: @BrianRisk It's been explained by the OP that the = sign submits the code. It does not occupy a spot on the display.

Answer (score 2):

How about

> 2222

We don't know what the janitor said exactly:

> it could be "twenty-four equals", but also "Two. Four equals."

Comment: 2222 doesn't work. But you feel like you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

> 12x2 or 24x1 or 19+5, 18+6, 17+7, 16+8, 15+9, 25-1, 26-2..... i am tired of trying more...

since there are 4 characters to fill it and all are equal to 24.

Comment: You beat me by 1 second.

Comment: or 22+2 or 23+1 or 21+3...etc

Comment: You try all of these and none of them work.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha You're close though.

Comment: Well we don't have a 0 on the keypad...

Comment: 19+5, 18+6, 17+7, 16+8, 15+9, 25-1, 26-2..... i am tired of trying more...

Comment: @Oray None of these work (and there's no - sign).

Comment: @Quark then the reverse to the previous answers, 2+22, 1+23 etc

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> 12*2

If that doesn't work, I would try

> 2*12

On the other hand, we may also do

> 4*6= or 6*4=

if the = sign counts as a symbol.

Comment: The equals sign doesn't work unless 4 entries are put in, and the other combinations don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear how the keypad works but I'm game to guess.

> 2 x 12 or 12 x 2. I am assuming the operators can be code entries.

Comment: Operators are code entries and equals submits it, but neither of these work.

Answer (score 1):

I type in

> 2424

To see what happens.  I could be here all day, though.

It doesn't work.

I try:

> 24==

I wonder, to myself, if I misunderstood the mumble.  I type in:

> 2+4=

Exasperated, I give one last try, before leaving:

> 23++

As I'm walking away, I realize that it would be a terrible first impression to just not try for more than a moment.  I quickly type in:

> +4+4  Maybe he meant Twin T4 and the + is the T?

A bang on the wall.

> 2+34  Two and 3 4?

Comment: You try 2424 (equals) and it doesn't work.

Comment: Neither of the other two enter because equals only can submit 4 previous entries.

Comment: +4+4 doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Guess#1: I type

> 204=

Because

> Twenty, Four, Equals

Comment: no zero on the keypad

Comment: oops.  Should I delete this, then?

Comment: that, my friend, is up to you. I ain't your dad.

Answer (score 0):

I'll press

> 789+

Because

> 7+8+9 = 24 and it uses a character from each column

Comment: 789+ doesn't work (and any combination of this)

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> 2184=

Because he slurred

> 218 ~ "twooneeight" ~ "twenty"

Or maybe

> 1234

because

> 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 = 24

Comment: You try 2184 and it doesn't work.

Comment: do I need to comment for you to get notified again? I edited in another guess.

Comment: 1234 (and any combination of it) doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I would just put 24equals as

> 204=

May be he just meant 20,4 and =

Answer (score -1):

24 equals

---

> 24 equal s

---

> 24 equal 5

---

> 24=5